# Is it possible to Fetch the Data from this "Users" Object to this layout?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am making this Simple Chat Application, where any person can register with his Name, Email and Pass , then Login and start chatting.

Messages are sent and received successfully from DB, now i am having the problem is "How can i get the Usernames of the Respective persons in the Chat Layout".

Also while registering process, i saved the username and Email to Database inside "Users" node.

This is what i have tried So Far :

This is my Database Screenshot :

[image: This is My DB screenshot]

This is how the app look so far :

[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKvfN.png)

Here is my SignUp Activity :

```
    private void DOSignup() {
        final String get_name = name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String get_email = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String get_password = password.getText().toString().trim();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(get_email,get_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    Log.e("Current User", firebaseUser.toString());
//                    String name = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
//                    Log.e("Name is :", name);


                    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                    GetUserName getUserName = new GetUserName(get_name,get_email);
                    String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();

                    databaseReference.child(id).setValue(getUserName);


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration failed! Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Model Class to save UserName and Email to DB :

```
public class GetUserName {

String username;
String email;

public GetUserName() {
}


public GetUserName(String username, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;

}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
```

}

This is my Model Class to show Messages :

```
    public class ChatModel {

    String messages;

    public ChatModel() {
    }

    public ChatModel(String messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }


    public String getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }
}
```

This is my chat_layout.xml :

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="Lacie"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTime"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="07-10-2016 (21:50:21)" />


</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/l1"

    android:background="@drawable/my_message"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Placeholder message"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
```

This is my ChatAdapter :

```
     @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_layout,
                parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ChatModel model) {

        ChatModel model1 = chatModelList.get(position);

        GetUserName getUserName = new GetUserName();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        holder.messages.setText(model1.getMessages());
        holder.userName.setText(databaseReference.getKey());
//        holder.userName.setText(getUserName.getUsername());

    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView messages,userName;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            messages = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_body);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
```

Please Give your Ideas to how can i get the Respective Usernames insted of "Lacie"  in chat_layout. Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? you need to be able to READ the data. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write u have to also make sure you have the rules in place for the node.

Comment: lacie isnt even in the DB, right? the screenshot you shows is nothing more than a view. you showed 0 code of getting data and storing that into a list and then putting the list into an adapter... you didnt hsow this. your login code has nothing to do with getting data.

Comment: I added the Adapter code too, btw "Lacie" is hardcoded, pls look at the xml @soldfor

Comment: but again, there is no code from what I can see where you are GETTING it from firebase? do you have that?

Comment: plus, the firebase code you are showing doesnt look like a chat node, its the user node. you are not showing enough here...

Comment: @soldfor added Chat Activity too ! Now pls have a look

Comment: like pulling teeth. whats inside of chatModelList? your code says it should be the model, but are they really being added? check the size through debugger... nd then check whats inside of it.

Comment: I think you dont know the answer. Its Ok

Comment: There is way too much code here to efficiently help. Please study [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) carefully to learn how to reproduce the problem in isolation, in a way that improves the chances we can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have reduced the code , please have a look now